# Desktop blogging software for Blogger

Tags: software-rec, internet-explorer, blogging

I'm using Blogger for my blog platform. I notice when I do a post that my layout looks totally messed up in IE, but also that Blogger is adding a lot of weird extraneous code.

Can anyone recommend a good desktop based software that will work with Blogger (for Windows) that will write a blog post that looks okay on Firefox and IE?

Comment: Is there _anything_ that looks okay on IE?

Comment: @grawity The intranet site at work. Built for IE, ofcourse!

Comment: You can download and use WordPress locally. That’s the move I made when Blogger dropped FTP support, and I couldn’t be happier.

Answer (score 3):

[Windows Live Writer](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-writer) supports Blogger.